# Running steamcmd on BOX86 in armhf chroot

Tags: steam, raspberrypi, box86

I want to run a game server on my raspberry pi 4 (4GB) using steamcmd. I have already set up a chroot and box86 to run a teamspeak 3 server.

I am following [these instructions](https://wiki.dawico.de/display/WIKI/7+Days+To+Die%3A+dedicated+Server+auf+Debian+installieren) and I am stuck on step 8, that is running steamcmd.sh.

I have altered the file to run box86, however whenever I run the shell script, it seems to update itself before executing, reverting my edits.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

STEAMROOT="$(cd "${0%/*}" && echo $PWD)"
STEAMCMD=`basename "$0" .sh`

UNAME=`uname`
if [ "$UNAME" == "Linux" ]; then
  STEAMEXE="${STEAMROOT}/linux32/${STEAMCMD}"
  PLATFORM="linux32"
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$STEAMROOT/$PLATFORM:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
else # if [ "$UNAME" == "Darwin" ]; then
  STEAMEXE="${STEAMROOT}/${STEAMCMD}"
  if [ ! -x ${STEAMEXE} ]; then
    STEAMEXE="${STEAMROOT}/Steam.AppBundle/Steam/Contents/MacOS/${STEAMCMD}"
  fi
  export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$STEAMROOT:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
  export DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH="$STEAMROOT:$DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH"
fi

ulimit -n 2048

MAGIC_RESTART_EXITCODE=42

if [ "$DEBUGGER" == "gdb" ] || [ "$DEBUGGER" == "cgdb" ]; then
  ARGSFILE=$(mktemp $USER.steam.gdb.XXXX)

  # Set the LD_PRELOAD varname in the debugger, and unset the global version.
  if [ "$LD_PRELOAD" ]; then
    echo set env LD_PRELOAD=$LD_PRELOAD >> "$ARGSFILE"
    echo show env LD_PRELOAD >> "$ARGSFILE"
    unset LD_PRELOAD
  fi

  $DEBUGGER -x "$ARGSFILE" --args /usr/local/bin/box86 "$STEAMEXE" "$@"
  rm "$ARGSFILE"
else
  $DEBUGGER /usr/local/bin/box86 "$STEAMEXE" "$@"
fi

STATUS=$?

if [ $STATUS -eq $MAGIC_RESTART_EXITCODE ]; then
    exec "$0" "$@"
fi
exit $STATUS
```

When I run this modified file I get this:

```
Box86 with Dynarec v0.2.1 7c0b11e built on May  6 2021 17:03:01
WARNING: setlocale('en_US.UTF-8') failed, using locale: 'C'. International characters may not work.
Redirecting stderr to '/root/Steam/logs/stderr.txt'
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[  0%] Checking for available updates...
[----] Verifying installation...
[  0%] Downloading update...
[  0%] Checking for available updates...
[----] Download complete.
[----] Extracting package...
[----] Extracting package...
[----] Extracting package...
[----] Extracting package...
[----] Installing update...
[----] Installing update...
[----] Installing update...
[----] Installing update...
[----] Installing update...
[----] Installing update...
[----] Installing update...
[----] Installing update...
[----] Cleaning up...
[----] Update complete, launching Steamcmd...
/opt/steamcmd/steamcmd.sh: line 37: /opt/steamcmd/linux32/steamcmd: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

If I use a different file name, such as `steamcmd_custom.sh` I get this:

```
Box86 with Dynarec v0.2.1 7c0b11e built on May  6 2021 17:03:01
Error: file is not found (check BOX86_PATH)
./steamcmd_custom.sh: line 38: 71730 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $DEBUGGER /usr/local/bin/box86 "$STEAMEXE" "$@"
```

And running

```bsh
box86 steamcmd
```

from `/opt/steamcmd/linux32` yields me

```
Box86 with Dynarec v0.2.1 7c0b11e built on May  6 2021 17:03:01
WARNING: setlocale('en_US.UTF-8') failed, using locale: 'C'. International characters may not work.
Redirecting stderr to '/root/Steam/logs/stderr.txt'
[  0%] Checking for available updates...
[----] Verifying installation...
[----] !!! Fatal Error: Failed to load steamconsole.so
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run it with

```bsh
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/steamcmd/linux32/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" box86 linux32/steamcmd
```

This will make the library path be available to steamcmd.