# Running Steamcmd on BOX86 with schroot -c debian-armhf

Tags: box86

I want to run a game server on my oracle cloud arm instance using steamcmd, but can't make it work.

When I run the script for start steamcmd, I got:

```
Box86 with Dynarec v0.2.5 9ee0ac92 built on Feb 19 2022 19:12:07
Error: reading elf header of ./steamcmd.sh, try to launch natively instead
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Then, I found [that answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1359142/running-steamcmd-on-box86-in-armhf-chroot/1393854#1393854). So I ran the code.
(Also, it has the same results if I just enter in the linux32 folder and run the steamcmd directly)

The first time I got:

```
Box86 with Dynarec v0.2.5 9ee0ac92 built on Feb 19 2022 19:12:07
Redirecting stderr to '/root/Steam/logs/stderr.txt'
ILocalize::AddFile() failed to load file "public/steambootstrapper_english.txt".
[  0%] Checking for available update...
[----] Downloading update (0 of 53847 KB)...
[  0%] Downloading update (48 of 53847 KB)...
[  0%] Downloading update (3874 of 53847 KB)...
[  7%] Downloading update (7065 of 53847 KB)...
[ 13%] Downloading update (9733 of 53847 KB)...
[ 18%] Downloading update (12226 of 53847 KB)...
[ 22%] Downloading update (14735 of 53847 KB)...
[ 27%] Downloading update (17164 of 53847 KB)...
[ 31%] Downloading update (19641 of 53847 KB)...
[ 36%] Downloading update (22153 of 53847 KB)...
[ 41%] Downloading update (24577 of 53847 KB)...
[ 45%] Downloading update (27320 of 53847 KB)...
[ 50%] Downloading update (29852 of 53847 KB)...
[ 55%] Downloading update (32286 of 53847 KB)...
[ 59%] Downloading update (34919 of 53847 KB)...
[ 64%] Downloading update (36171 of 53847 KB)...
[ 67%] Downloading update (37430 of 53847 KB)...
[ 69%] Downloading update (38683 of 53847 KB)...
[ 71%] Downloading update (40047 of 53847 KB)...
[ 74%] Downloading update (41318 of 53847 KB)...
[ 76%] Downloading update (42556 of 53847 KB)...
[ 79%] Downloading update (43807 of 53847 KB)...
[ 81%] Downloading update (45166 of 53847 KB)...
[ 83%] Downloading update (46411 of 53847 KB)...
[ 86%] Downloading update (47647 of 53847 KB)...
[ 88%] Downloading update (48883 of 53847 KB)...
[ 90%] Downloading update (50221 of 53847 KB)...
[ 93%] Downloading update (51447 of 53847 KB)...
[ 95%] Downloading update (52686 of 53847 KB)...
[ 97%] Downloading update (53847 of 53847 KB)...
[100%] Download Complete.
[----] Applying update...
[----] Extracting package...
[----] Extracting package...
[----] Extracting package...
[----] Extracting package...
[----] Installing update...
[----] Installing update...
[----] Installing update...
[----] Installing update...
[----] Installing update...
[----] Installing update...
[----] Installing update...
[----] Installing update...
[----] Cleaning up...
[----] Update complete, launching...
CWorkThreadPool::~CWorkThreadPool: work processing queue not empty: 7 items discarded.
```

Then second time:

```
Box86 with Dynarec v0.2.5 9ee0ac92 built on Feb 19 2022 19:12:07
max open descriptors set to 9216
WARNING: setlocale('en_US.UTF-8') failed, using locale: 'C'. International characters may not work.
Redirecting stderr to '/root/Steam/logs/stderr.txt'
[  0%] Checking for available updates...
[----] Verifying installation...
[  0%] Downloading update...
[  0%] Checking for available updates...
[----] Download complete.
[----] Extracting package...
[----] Extracting package...
[----] Extracting package...
[----] Extracting package...
[----] Installing update...
[----] Installing update...
[----] Installing update...
[----] Installing update...
[----] Installing update...
[----] Installing update...
[----] Installing update...
[----] Installing update...
[----] Cleaning up...
[----] Update complete, launching Steamcmd...
```

And all other times if I run the command:

```
Box86 with Dynarec v0.2.5 9ee0ac92 built on Feb 19 2022 19:12:07
max open descriptors set to 9216
WARNING: setlocale('en_US.UTF-8') failed, using locale: 'C'. International characters may not work.
Redirecting stderr to '/root/Steam/logs/stderr.txt'
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[  0%] Checking for available updates...
[----] Verifying installation...
[----] !!! Fatal Error: Failed to load steamconsole.so
```

In the log files of Steam directory, there is a "Shutdown" in every last line of each time I ran the command.

I followed [this guide](https://forum.armbian.com/topic/16584-install-box86-on-arm64/) to install box86. The only diff is that after the last "make" I run a make install, exited the chroot and systemctl restart systemd-binfmt

screenfetch:

``````
                          ./+o+-       ubuntu@ubuntuarm
                  yyyyy- -yyyyyy+      OS: Ubuntu 20.04 focal
               ://+//////-yyyyyyo      Kernel: aarch64 Linux 5.11.0-1028-oracle
           .++ .:/++++++/-.+sss/`      Uptime: 14h 49m
         .:++o:  /++++++++/:--:/-      Packages: 660
        o:+o+:++.`..```.-/oo+++++/     Shell: bash 5.0.17
       .:+o:+o/.          `+sssoo+/    Disk: 4.0G / 55G (8%)
  .++/+:+oo+o:`             /sssooo.   CPU: 2x Unknown
 /+++//+:`oo+o               /::--:.   GPU:
 \+/+o+++`o++o               ++////.   RAM: 370MiB / 11948MiB
  .++.o+++oo+:`             /dddhhh.
       .+.o+oo:.          `oddhhhh+
        \+.++o+o``-````.:ohdhhhhh+
         `:o+++ `ohhhhhhhhyo++os:
           .o:`.syhhhhhhh/.oo++o`
               /osyyyyyyo++ooo+++/
                   ````` +oo+++o\:
                          `oo++.
``````

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @David It's the 20.04, I will update the question, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me with [the guide you posted](https://forum.armbian.com/topic/16584-install-box86-on-arm64/), try changing the command's path, if steamcmd is installed in /home/ubuntu/ try these two commands. Otherwise just change where it says /home/ubuntu/ to where your steamcmd folder is located.

```
$ schroot -c debian-armhf

$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/ubuntu/steamcmd/linux32/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" ~/box86/build/box86 /home/ubuntu/steamcmd/linux32/steamcmd
```